# Failure reason: "Host not found" Received status code: "502" - Creating a destination in SAP cockpit

Tags: odata, sap-fiori

I am new to SAP and development of SAP Fiori Application. I want to create a project consuming oData service.

I have created a SAP cloud platform Cockpit trial account and created a destination for my in house development gateway.

When I click on test connection, it shows host not found: 502.

[image: Here is a image of my destination configuration.]

I am not able to access oData connection url without saml2=disabled parameter, so tried with Basic authentication using my SAP user.

SAP is on Azure cloud. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your hardware landscape you might need to configure SAP Cloud Connector, 
as documented [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cca91383641e40ffbe03bdc78f00f681/Cloud/en-US/e6c7616abb5710148cfcf3e75d96d596.html):
“The Cloud Connector serves as a link between SAP Cloud Platform applications and on-premise systems. It combines an easy setup with a clear configuration of the systems that are exposed to the SAP Cloud Platform. You can also control the resources available for the cloud applications in those systems. Thus, you can benefit from your existing assets without exposing the whole internal landscape.

The Cloud Connector runs as on-premise agent in a secured network and acts as a reverse invoke proxy between the on-premise network and SAP Cloud Platform. Due to its reverse invoke support, you don't need to configure the on-premise firewall to allow external access from the cloud to internal systems.”

And also look [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/825270ffffe74d9f988a0f0066ad59f0/Cloud/en-US/5c3debce758a470e8342161457fd6f70.html):
“If your remote system resides behind a firewall (proxy type OnPremise), the following prerequisites must be met:
You have set up Cloud Connector and defined a virtual host mapping for the system.”

Also take a look [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/e12d8683adfa4471ac4edd40809b9038/latest/en-US/09c24809d79446728ed27ace7d0262af.html):
“Maintain Destinations for SAP Cloud Platform Connector
In the SAP Cloud Platform Cockpit, maintain destinations for each target system to enable communication via the SAP Cloud Platform Connector.
For on premise systems, make sure to select the Proxy Type OnPremise.”

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm a part of IT team. Does this cloud connector set up has to be done by SAP BASIS team? what kind of access do I need to create a connector from my trial sap cloud platform account? Many thanks.

Comment: In the [SAP Cloud Connector](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cca91383641e40ffbe03bdc78f00f681/Cloud/en-US/e6c7616abb5710148cfcf3e75d96d596.html) documentation, in the Scenarios section, you'll find a image called, "Connecting Cloud Applications to On-Premise Systems" that outlines the steps. The SAP Cloud Connector usually needs to be setup in your On-Premise network.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue yesterday night. This generally has to do with some config problems. 
For me, it was the Proxy settings. it was set to 'Internet'.
It had to be set to 'OnPremise'. After doing that, it got successfully connected.